# Combine similar validation on multiple textboxes, with differing validation result text

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a report which can be filtered by `StartDate` + `EndDate`, `BookingID`, `CardNumber` and `Amount`.

These are represented with 2 date pickers and 4 textboxes (`CardNumber` is split into 2 textboxes) and there is a `Search` button to return the report. My Search click code below is working fine by I'm wondering can I combine some or all of my validation code to reduce the amount of lines of code? Most of the validation code is similar I.E checking that `BookingID`, `CardNumber` and `Amount` are entered as ints.

I'm aware this question is bordering on a code review, so please let me know if it should be asked elsewhere.

```
protected void ibtnSearch_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    lblInputMessage.Visible = false;
    DateTime dtStart, dtEnd;
    bool isGood = DateTime.TryParse(txtEndDate.Text, out dtEnd);

    if (DateTime.TryParse(txtStartDate.Text, out dtStart))
    {
        if (txtEndDate.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            dtEnd = DateTime.Now;
            isGood = true;
        }
    }

    if (txtBookingID.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        int newBookingID;
        if (int.TryParse(txtBookingID.Text, out newBookingID))
        {
            isGood = true;
        }

        else
        {
            lblInputMessage.Visible = true;
            lblInputMessage.Text = "Please enter a valid BookingID.";
            return;
        }
    }

    if (txtAmount.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        int newAmount;
        if (int.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, out newAmount))
        {
            isGood = true;
        }

        else
        {
            lblInputMessage.Visible = true;
            lblInputMessage.Text = "Please enter a valid Amount.";
            return;
        }
    }

    if (txtCardNumber1.Text.Length > 0 || txtCardNumber2.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        int newCardNumber1;
        int newCardNumber2;
        if (int.TryParse(txtCardNumber1.Text, out newCardNumber1) && (int.TryParse(txtCardNumber2.Text, out newCardNumber2)))
        {
            isGood = true;
        }

        else
        {
            lblInputMessage.Visible = true;
            lblInputMessage.Text = "Please enter a valid Card Number.";
            return;
        }
    }

    if (isGood)
    {
        if (dtStart > dtEnd)
        {
            lblInputMessage.Visible = true;
            lblInputMessage.Text = "End Date must be greater than Start Date.";
            return;
        }

        lblInputMessage.Visible = false;
        LoadGridData(true);
        ajaxCollapsiblePanel1.Collapsed = true;
        ajaxCollapsiblePanel1.ClientState = "true";
        pnlContainer.Visible = true;
    }

    else
    {
        lblInputMessage.Visible = true;
        lblInputMessage.Text = "Please enter a valid date.";
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would rather opt for the [`IDataErrorInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, as it supports validation of your input as well, combined with binding support on multiple presentation frameworks. On the other hand, if you are using this webbased, you might also look into [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/validation-controls-in-asp-net/)

Comment: Is it windows form application or ASP.NET ? For ASP.NET I would rather use validation controls to perform basic validation at the client side only.

Comment: @Icepickle, I will have a look at your suggestions thank you.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya it is ASP.NET. Sorry I should have tagged it originally in the question. Tag added now.

Comment: Did you try using Validationcontrols?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya Yes but I couldn't get it to display the validation messages as I would like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could modify it to use IDataErrorInfo and do something like this.

```
public string Error
{
    get { return String.Empty; }
}

public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        String errorMessage = String.Empty;
        switch (columnName)
        {
            case "Variable1":
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Variable1))
                {
                    errorMessage = "Variable1 is required";
                }
                break;
            case "Variable2":
                if (Variable2 < 10)
                {
                    errorMessage = "Variable2 can't be less than 10";
                }
                break;
        }
        return errorMessage;
    }
}
```

This tutorial https://tarundotnet.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-idataerrorinfo-in-wpf/ covers the basics.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!